# Solving leetcode #994 Rotting Oranges

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to solve leetcode `#994` [Rotting Oranges](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotting-oranges/) in JavaScript.
The Problem Statement is as follows:

You are given an `m x n grid` where each cell can have one of three values:

- `0` representing an empty cell,
- `1` representing a fresh orange, or
- `2` representing a rotten orange.

Every minute, any fresh orange that is 4-directionally adjacent to a rotten orange becomes rotten.
Return *the minimum number of minutes that must elapse until no cell has a fresh orange*. If *this is impossible, return -1*.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
var orangesRotting = function(grid) {
    if(!grid) return -1;

    let q = [], rows = grid.length, cols = grid[0].length, fresh = 0, time = 0;
    const dirs = [[1,0],[-1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]];

    for(let r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
        for(let c = 0; c < cols; ++c){
            if(grid[r][c] === 1) fresh += 1;
            if(grid[r][c] === 2) q.push([r,c]);
        }
    }

    while(q.length !== 0 || fresh > 0){
        for(let i = 0; i < q.length; ++i){
            const [currRow,currCol] = q.shift();

            for(const [dirRow,dirCol] of dirs){
                const [newRow,newCol] = [currRow+dirRow,currCol+dirCol];

                if(newRow < 0 || newRow === grid.length || newCol < 0 || newCol === grid[0].length || grid[newRow][newCol] !== 1) continue;
                grid[newRow][newCol] = 2;
                fresh -= 1;
                q.push([newRow,newCol]);
            }
        }
        time += 1;
    }

    return fresh > 0 ? -1 : time;
};
```

I tried running this code but it's giving me a `Time Limit Exceeded` error, this error means that I'm stuck in an infinite loop however I just can't seem to figure out why?

Comment: You get also this error if your algorithm does not have the required complexity class and is thus too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do `q.length !== 0 && fresh > 0` instead of `q.length !== 0 || fresh > 0` to  avoid `Time Limit Exceeded` error